# Можно ли в приложение под android вшить код вызова js

Tags: javascript, java, android

Можно ли вшить в приложение  код вызова локального или удаленного ява скрипта ?
Допустим если это приложение браузер , при серфинге наш яваскрипт будет менять дизайн сайта . Я знаю что есть user js. А так можно что бы вот вшить и все ?

Comment: В смысле в приложении с `WebView` применять скрипт к каждой странице?

Comment: Допустим я дикампилирую chrome , туда встрою js , или обработчик js, который будет  выполнять скрипты которые лежат в папке ?
Будет как аля свой userjs  . Для андройд ведь еще не сделали под chrome , вот я для себя чисто )
А скрипт будет  добавлять  элементы в Страницу, менять ее дизайн и т.д

Answer (score 0):

Можно, [WebView.evaluateJavascript();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Answer (score -1):

у хромиума открытый исходный код, так что не надо ничего дИкАмпилировать, надо собрать мощный комп, поставить линукс, запастись терпением, поднакопить опыта, а года через 2 хотя бы вернуться и собрать исходник в десятки гигабайт.

но к первоначальному вопросу это не имеет отношения. в таком случае и так ясно, что можно.